Finding a way out of the labyrinth
Problem:
You need to get out of the labyrinth. You don't know how many rooms it has or what its map is. You can move freely in both directions along all corridors, all rooms and corridors look the same (rooms may differ only in the number of corridors). Let k be the number of corridors between rooms.
Propose an algorithm that finds a way out of the labyrinth, or proves that there is no way out. Complexity should be O(k) transitions between rooms. You have an unlimited number of indistinguishable  coins at your disposal, which you can leave in the rooms (may more than one in a room).
Formulation of the problem using graph theory:
We need to traverse all vertices of the graph for O(k), where k is the number of edges in the graph. The graph is unknown in advance. When visiting each vertex, we can see how many edges this vertex has. It is possible to mark visited vertices with indistinguishable coins (and it is possible to leave more than 1 coin in the room).
My thoughts:
I have had two attempts at a solution, one using BFS and one using DFS, but in both of them I encounter difficulties and need to introduce some modifications.
1. BFS: Starting from the starting room we visit one room on each corridor. Put a coin in the visited room and return to the starting room. Then from the starting room go first to the rooms of the first level and in each of them also visit all rooms at a distance of $1$ on each of the new corridors of this room. We put a coin if there was no coin in the room. Then take two steps back, returning to the starting room.
Until we find the exit, repeat these steps, increasing the range of each next move by $1$.
However, there are two problems that confuse me here:
1.1) Will the fact that I walk back to the starting room each time preserve the linear asymptotics of the solution? It seems to me that it doesn't anymore.
1.2) In this solution, how do I resolve the situation where there are no solutions? There must be some way to check the fact of visiting all rooms. The possible existence of cycles is especially complicated here.
2. DFS: Do DFS, starting from the starting room, with corridors bypassed, always starting from the rightmost one (if there are several corridors in the room). We leave $3$ groups of coins in the room: 1st group of coins - opening time, 2nd group of coins - corridor counter, 3rd group of coins - closing time. We do it this way: fix a discrete counter of opening time (starting from $1$ in the starting room), increasing it by $1$ at each step (opening or closing). (i.e. in the second room in 1st pile of coins we will already put $2$ coins, etc.), and also in the second pile of coins we will put the counter on the number of corridors (before we are going to go from the room along the corridor, which has not yet walked, add a coin to the second group. If the number of coins in the second group becomes equal to the number of corridors in this room, then consider that we have passed all the corridors from this room and then add to the third pile as many coins as now on the time counter (the condition must also be fulfilled here that all descendant vertices are already closed)).
If we go this way to the starting top and close it, it means that there was no exit.
The problem in this solution: if there are cyclic paths in the graph, then we can pass some paths without closing vertices in them and return to the parent. Then the parent cannot be closed, because the descendants are still not closed. But in order to close a descendant it is necessary to pass this path again. But there is no guarantee that in case of a labyrinth with a lot of branching, we have the right to close vertices at the second pass through them.
I have absolutely no idea how to upgrade counters with coins in order to solve problematic situations with cycles. I will be grateful for any ideas or other solution.

I think that more detail is needed.  For many maze designs, you can always escape by putting your hand  on a wall as you walk (as there can't be an embedded circle).  Other designs avoid this trick (as there might be free standing walls, for example).  But here we have no information on matters like this.

Hi! This is a theoretical problem from a course on algorithms. At the beginning it says that we don't know the map of the maze. We need to come up with a theoretical algorithm of a given complexity without knowing the number of rooms and the map of the maze in advance

My comments had nothing to do with any map, just with structural properties of the labyrinth.  For instance, does my strategy work?  That is, can I just hold one hand to a wall as I walk?

Maybe it would be better to phrase this as a graph theory problem, where, at any node, you can see how many edges you could follow and you are able to mark the nodes (and edges?) you visit (though I guess you can't mark them in a way which distinguishes them?  Are the coins distinct in some way?)

I don't think so. Imagine that the first room has a corridor to the right leading to another room with a corridor to the right, etc. There is no prohibition on cycles in the problem.

Consider using your coins not to mark rooms you have entered, but to mark corridors you have transited. And consider how with those coins you could record not only whether you had transited along a corridor, but also in which direction.

I don't think the labyrinth design is very important here. When I tried to solve it, I imagined that a room is just a vertex of the graph, and the corridor between rooms is an edge of the graph connecting two vertices (rooms).
The coins are indistinguishable (but I think it's possible to put more than one coin in a room, that is, thus making a counter or multiple counters). You can leave coins in the rooms, you can't leave coins in the corridors.

I don't understand the memory constraints. Once you return to the starting room, do you still remember which corridors are already explored?

I don't think so. Otherwise it's not clear why the problem gives coins for attendance marks. I am trying to solve the problem based on the fact that the person did not remember where he went and should make further decisions based on the coins left behind.

@lulu : I think that your strategy is excluded here. Disciple ; you wrote in original message :  how do I resolve the situation where there are no solutions? My understanding is that there is always a solution, a way to exit the labyrinth. The question is ; do we have a solution in $O(k)$ ; it means, are we able to find the exit in a "reasonable" number of steps.

@Lourrran, maybe I didn't understand your message, but here is what is required: there is a maze and we don't know if there is an exit in it at all. We need to either find the exit or prove that there is no exit (in this case, obviously, we need to go round all the rooms). The complexity of such an algorithm must be linear in the number of corridors.

You have an infinite number of coins. It is clear that you can put more than 1 coin in any room, and it is certainly an important element of the strategy.

Ok. Before you edit the question, it was not crystal-clear for me.

Do the DFS, but when you explore a new corridor, if the room you land already has some coins, get back immediately without doing anything

@caduk, suppose there is a cycle in a graph and from some intermediate vertex of the cycle there is another path or several paths. Then when we get to this vertex for the first time, we mark it as passed, but obviously it must be visited more than once (at least as many times as there are edges in it).

My suggestion is to walk the classic DFS tree. If you encounter an already visited note, go back. If you visited all the paths, go back.

@caduk, I think there's a problem here distinguishing the infinite loop from the required number of visits to each vertex. The problem comes from the fact that we do not know full graph in advance. At what moment should I mark a vertex as visited? At the first visit? Or for example, if a vertex has m edges, do I consider a vertex visited only if I have visited it m times and all visits were on different edges?

Yes, you mark it at the first visit. If you encounter it, go back anyway, you will visit the remaining corridor of this room later.

@caduk If you've got this problem figured out, why not write an answer?

I will assume that we have no memory, so we can't make a mental map of the maze.
Repeat the following steps:

If the room has fewer coins than exits, add a coin to the room. Else, if the room already has $n$ coins, STOP, there is no exit.
Take the first corridor on the left of the corridor you just came from (if you are in the starting room, pick a corridor at random).
If it is the EXIT, great. If the room you arrive in has no coins, go to step 1. Otherwise, immediately go back without leaving any coins, and go to step 1.

By doing this, you will perform a DFS exploration of the graph. If there is no exit, you will stop after returning to the first node with all exits explored and each edge will be visited exactly twice (once in each direction, with a back and forth in step 3 counting only once).

Is this algorithm $O(k)$?

@RobArthan yes, as I said each corridor is used at most fourth (the  worst case is two back and forths)

I see. I hadn't taken on board what $k$ was here.
